Store translations in DLL instead of RESX file in a C# .NET8 Forms application
I'm currently developing a C# .NET8 WinForms application that should be multilanguage as it will be deployed in multiple countries in Europe.
I've installed MAT (Multilanguage App Toolkit) Extension for VS2022 and Multilingual Editor for XLF files, and I've managed to correctly add the required languages and translations inside RESX files.
I've noticed that every translation resource file is embedded in the final EXE. Is it possible to avoid this behavior and use external DLLs to dynamically load languages at runtime?
Basically I would like to have a default language embedded inside the application (e.g. English) and then have external DLLs like "App.lt-LT.dll" or "App.it-IT.dll" for example. The application should load the corresponding DLL based on CultureInfo specified during application startup. This will also allow to list available languages inside the UI, and correct mistakes without re-deploying the entire application, but only the language DLL.
Is it possible to do something like this?
I am using VS2022 .NET8 (C# 12). Currently targeting Windows 10 Enterprise.

Normally, when language resources are compiled from .resx files, they go into satellite assemblies, just as you described. The main .exe can contain only one language (specified by NeutralResourcesLanguageAttribute), whereas the others are placed in subfolders, eg. lt-LT\App.resources.dll. What is the Build Action for the .resx files in Visual Studio? Btw. I actually prefer using the .resx files directly, so they can be updated or even generated at run-time, for any language.

I have "Embedded resource" on each .resx file. I noticed that multilang DLLs are created like you said, but I can't understand how to build those DLL separately from my application.

That's a bit cumbersome, but here is how.

I've managed to create separate assemblies like you said. I think this could be a good solution for me. The only thing I noticed is that I have to put satellite assemblies in application root directory (ech one in its own locale directory). Is it possible to create for example a "Lang" subfolder and then load assemblies from there?

Unfortunately, no. Though if you want to use the .resx files directly (so anyone can easily create their own localization without compiling a binary resource) you can use my libraries I mentioned above. Its ResXResourceManager (or HybridResourceManager to handle also binary resources) class has a ResXResourcesDir property that you can set to Lang if you wish.

I managed to create a custom DynamicComponentResourceManager inherited from main ResourceManager (instead of ComponentResourceManager, because it lacks of some properties), and dynamically load the assemblies with Assembly.LoadFile('filename_with_locales.dll') and then iterating each control in the application to apply the correct resource. I have also created an extension method for type Control to call directly from every Form or any other control. I know, It's a bit of a overkill, but it's working. I will update the answer as soon as I refactor and clean the code. Thank you anyway

I'm glad you managed to find a solution.
